# Why doesn't Twilio/Rest/Client throw exception with bad credentials?

Tags: initialization, client, twilio-php

I've written a php class to initialize the Twilio rest client and provide methods for sending and deleting messages to reduce the code in my ivr a bit.

When writing an integration test, I wanted to ensure that I can handle an exception when the credentials aren't correct.

However, the rest client doesn't throw a ConfigurationException and instead just returns a client with the bad credentials in the username/password properties and thus subsequent calls fail. I don't understand why this isn't working. Perhaps I'm missing something in dependencies that would expose the exception?

This isn't how I would test this normally but I wrote a test strictly to see if I could detect an exception and the test doesn't detect an exception. The client happily initializes with bad credentials. I seem to remember this working differently.

```
    use Twilio\Rest\Client as TwilioClient;

    ......
```

`$this->expectException(ConfigurationException::class); $testClient = new TwilioClient("bad_sid","bad_token"); $this->logger->debug("Test Client: " . print_r($testClient,true)); self::assertInstanceOf(TwilioClient::class,$testClient);`

Expected the client to fail on initialization when bad credentials are supplied.

Didn't fail.

Answer (score 0):

So, after much hair-pulling I've discovered that this is due to the rest client not throwing an exception unless the credentials are empty.

The client happily initializes with bad credentials and only throws a configuration error if the credentials aren't supplied. After supplying nulls, the test passes.

This does present a problem as if one were to supply bad credentials in a .env file, no issue would be exposed until a call to send a message or make a recording via the client was made.